# How to visualize a sine wave with custom frequency and amplitude?

Tags: javascript, html, math

I am trying to plot a sine wave into the canvas: I want to control the frequency like if I say:

10 freq, I want to see 10 periods of oscillating waves with the same amplitude etc.

Currently 10 freq works ok, but If I say 49 frequency, I see a weird change in amplitude. What is causing this and what is my error?

In the example I overlap two different waves to save on space.

```js
let element = document.getElementById('app');
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

canvas.width = 320;
canvas.height = 180;

let bounds = element.getBoundingClientRect();
canvas.style.width = bounds.width + 'px';
canvas.style.height = bounds.height + 'px';

element.appendChild(canvas);

let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 320, 180);

let points = [];

function fSin(freq, amplitude) {
  return x => 
  Math.sin(x / 100 * freq * Math.PI * 2) * amplitude;
}

function generate(ff) {
  let res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    res.push([i, ff(i)]);
  }
  return res;
}

function drawPoints(points, xscale = 1, yscale = 1) {
  ctx.moveTo(points[0][0] * xscale, 90 - points[0][1] * yscale);
  for (let i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(points[i][0] * xscale, 90 - points[i][1] * yscale);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}


points = generate(fSin(10, 10));
points = points.concat(generate(fSin(49, 10)));

drawPoints(points, 3.2, 2);
```

```css
#app {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  margin: auto;
}

#app canvas {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is just an illusion due to [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing), the interplay between the sampling rate (where the points are captured) and the sine function. If you were to zoom in and add more in-between points, you'd see that it's still a regular sine function. The omission of the in-between points due to sampling and connecting those samples with lines distorts the actual curve.

For fun, I modified your code a bit and added a slider. In this version, single pixel points are drawn instead, and the slider lets to interactively adjust the frequency. You can see as you increase/decrease the frequency how the samples seem to form weird patterns.

```js
let element = document.getElementById('app');
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

canvas.width = 320;
canvas.height = 180;
canvas.style.width = '320px';
canvas.style.height = '180px';

let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

element.appendChild(canvas);

function fSin(freq, amplitude) {
  return x => Math.sin(x / 100 * freq * Math.PI * 2) * amplitude;
}

let slider = document.createElement('input');
slider.type = 'range';
slider.min = 0;
slider.max = 100;
slider.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const frequency = slider.value;

  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 320, 180);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';

  const ff = fSin(frequency, 10);

  for (let i = 0; i < canvas.width; i++) {
    ctx.fillRect(i, 90 - ff(i) * 2, 1, 1);
  }
});
element.appendChild(slider);
```

```css
#app {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  margin: auto;
}

#app canvas {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: In your version amplitude is constant, can you make it look variable?

Comment: Looking at a frequency of 49, imagine now drawing lines between each point. They'll oscillate up and down seemingly in a rising and falling amplitude. In the original code, there were only 100 points on the horizontal axis, so it's even fewer samples distorting the full picture.